# has_many configuration for Ember-Data and Active Model Serializers with embedded IDs and sideloading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, ember-data, active-model-serializers

I know that Ember-Data is supposed to be compatible with Active Model Serializers by design, but they seem to be out of step on serializing `has_many` relationships with embedded IDs.

For example, the serializer

```
class PostSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  embed :ids
  has_many :comments
end
```

produces the JSON

```
{
    "post": {
        "comment_ids": [...]
    }
}
```

But the default configuration in Ember Data,

```
App.Post = DS.Model.extend({
  DS.hasMany('App.Comment'),
});

App.Comment = DS.Model.extend();
```

expects the comments association to be serialized as `comments: [...]` without the `_ids` suffix (see [the relationships sub-section of the REST adapter section of the Ember.js guide](http://emberjs.com/guides/models/the-rest-adapter/)).

I tried the following as a work-around:

```
class PostSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attribute :comments
  def comments
    object.comment_ids
  end
end
```

It works, but adding `embed :ids, :include => true` in order to enable side-loading now does nothing since AMS doesn't know that it's an association.

Edit: I am using the `active_model_serializers (0.6.0)` gem and Ember-Data revision 11

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For ember-data 1.0.0-beta.3 I ended up using this:

```
App.ApplicationSerializer = DS.ActiveModelSerializer.extend({});
```

As explained here: [Transition Guide](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/TRANSITION.md#underscored-keys-_id-and-_ids)

Works very nicely!

Answer (score 3):

You can try to configure the right mapping in the adapter at the client side

```
DS.RESTAdapter.map('App.Post', { comments: { keyName: 'comment_ids' } });
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm using active_model_serializers 0.6.0 and ember_data 11. I don't see behaviour you are reporting.

My serializer:

```
class CentreSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  embed :ids

  attributes :id, :name
  has_many :rooms
end
```

The output of localhost:3000/centres/1.json

```
{
  centre: {
    id: 1,
    name: "Centre0",
    rooms: [
      1,
      2,
      3,
      4,
      5
    ]
  }
}
```

In my case the rails app is producing the correctly formed json before it even gets across to ember. You shouldn't have to resort to mapping on the client side.

Comment: I was actually using an edge build of AMS. It seems the serialization of `has_many` associations was changed recently.

Comment: In that case, can't you just use the key: argument as documented at https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers#associations ?

Comment: Yes, that does the trick too. I was searching for an option like that earlier, but I overlooked it.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that [this commit](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/commit/7f87c9b3f2bb26372d75a5c10025e5dd881d6688) is responsible for the situation. When AMS was updated to serialize `has_one` associations as `association_id` (bringing AMS into compliance with ember-data), it was also modified to serialize `belongs_to` associations as `association_ids`.

Comment: The issue has been addressed in this [pull request](https://github.com/emberjs/data/pull/727).